# java recursion find the last index of a character in a string

Tags: java, string, recursion

Here is what I have for method `lastIndexOf` , `ch` is the character to match, and `str` is the source string.

```
public static int lastIndexOf(char ch, String str) {
    // check for null string or empty string
    if (str.length() == 0 || str == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    int indexInRest = lastIndexOf(ch, str.substring(1));
    char first = str.charAt(0);

    // recursive call to find the last matching character
    if (first == ch) {
        return 1 + indexInRest; // this might not work properly
    } else
        return indexInRest;
}
```

If in my class' main method I call:

```
    System.out.println(lastIndexOf('r', "recurse"));
    System.out.println(lastIndexOf('p', "recurse"));
```

I got:

```
1
-1
```

The desired result is:

```
4
-1
```

Suggestion, please.

Comment: and what is wrong with the existing method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29 ?

Comment: yes, i need suggestions.

Comment: You're searching from the first character to the last, instead of from the last character to the first.  Also, your null check should be first and the length check second.

Comment: int lastIndexOf(int char) <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29> takes an unicode value of character. As this is a homework for recursion. I definitely cannot use that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about taking the *functional* approach..

```
public static int lastIndexOf(char ch, String str) {
    if (str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == ch) { return str.length() -1; }
    if (str.length() <= 1) { return -1; }
    return lastIndexOf(ch, str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This must be homework because there would be no point to writing this method since String.lastIndexOf() exists in the API, and using recursion to do this going to be slow and use a lot of memory.

Here a hint.  Right now your algorithm is chopping characters off the front ( substring(1) ) and comparing them.  lastIndexOf() should start by removing characters at the back of the String looking for a match then quit when it finds one.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `String.lastIndexOf` like this:

```
str.lastIndexOf(ch)
```

Comment: Likely because it's homework and the teacher has requested reinventing this wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`String#lastIndexOf(int ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) implementation as a general guideline,

```
public int lastIndexOf(int ch) {
    return lastIndexOf(ch, value.length - 1);
}

public int lastIndexOf(int ch, int fromIndex) {
    if (ch < Character.MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT) {
        // handle most cases here (ch is a BMP code point or a
        // negative value (invalid code point))
        final char[] value = this.value;
        int i = Math.min(fromIndex, value.length - 1);
        for (; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (value[i] == ch) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    } else {
        return lastIndexOfSupplementary(ch, fromIndex);
    }
}

private int lastIndexOfSupplementary(int ch, int fromIndex) {
    if (Character.isValidCodePoint(ch)) {
        final char[] value = this.value;
        char hi = Character.highSurrogate(ch);
        char lo = Character.lowSurrogate(ch);
        int i = Math.min(fromIndex, value.length - 2);
        for (; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (value[i] == hi && value[i + 1] == lo) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And this,

```
lastIndexOf(ch, value.length - 1);
```

`value` is the target String as a character array.

Comment: It's important to note that Java uses the iterative approach...you'll need to convert this to a recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change to:

```
if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
```

Because a NPE could raise if `str` is `null`

Add a `deep` paramater to your code like this:

```
public static int lastIndexOf(char ch, String str, int deep) {
```

And increment its value every recursive call

```
int indexInRest = lastIndexOf(ch, str.substring(1), deep++);
```

then, in the return sentence, add deep to your returned value:

```
return 1 + indexInRest + deep; // this might not work properly
```

Call the function the first time with `deep = 0`, or better yet, make the two parameter method `lastIndexOf` call the 3 parameters version of `lastIndexOf` with the `deep` parameter set to 0

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Matcher` in order to anticipate evolution of string analysis asked by your homework:

```
public int getlastMatch(String searchPattern,String textString) {
       int index = -1;
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchPattern);
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textString);

       while(matcher.find()) {
               index = matcher.start();
       }
       return index;
   }
```

where `textString` may be your concerned character.

Thus returning the last occurence of a part of string within a string.